# Extracting data from a file

Tags: sed, grep, unix

I have a file `results.txt` which is like:

```
a.txt
{some data}
success!!

b.txt
{some data}
success!!

c.txt
{some data}
error!!
```

I want to extract data from it. I want an output like:

```
a.txt: success
b.txt: success
c.txt: error
```

The problem is that the `{some data}` part can be arbitrarily long.

***How can this be done?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat file
a.txt
{some
  blah
data}
success!!

b.txt
{some data}
success!!

c.txt
{some data}
error!!

$ awk 'BEGIN{ FS="[{}]|\n";RS=""}{gsub(/!!/,"",$NF);print $1":"$NF}' file
a.txt:success
b.txt:success
c.txt:error
```

Update:

```
$ awk -vRS= -vFS="\n" '{print $1":"$NF}' file
a.txt:success!!
b.txt:success!!
c.txt:error!!
```

Comment: You *might* have taken his curly brackets too literally :)

Comment: yes, you might be right. but who knows ;), in any case, the second version can be used.

Answer (score 3):

awk:

```
BEGIN {
  state=0
}

state==0 && /.txt$/ {
  filename=$0
  state=1
  next
}

state==1 && /!!$/ {
  print filename ": " gensub(/!!$/, "", $0)
  state=0
  next
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to BEGIN with that "state=0" ? Wasn't possible to begin directly with the /.txt/ event ?

Comment: Possibly, but I didn't want to chance it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following way also.

```
sed -e 's/^{some data}$//g;/^$/d;' results.txt | sed '$!N;s/\n/: /'
```

Answer (score 1):

That works for me:

```
cat result.txt | xargs |sed 's/\ {[^}]*}/:/g' | sed 's/!! /\n/g'

a.txt: success
b.txt: success
c.txt: error!!
```

Answer (score 0):

`cat results.txt | grep -E "(([a-z]\.txt)|((success)|(error)!!))" | tr -d '\n' | sed 's/!!/!!\n/'`
 should do it. You might have to replace `\n` with a literal newline though.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{print $1": "$4}' RS="\n\n" results.txt
```